# Use Entity in non JPA module

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on a multi module java project and I ended up creating a module for the shared model and services.

I have a problem because one module (using Spring Data REST) uses JPA entities and they need to be shared with other modules in the form of simple POJO (without database sync). At the moment I have duplicated code without any JPA/Hibernate annotations but this is surely not the way to go. Any clue how I can proceed please ?

Comment: To turn an entity into a POJO, one can _detach_ them from the PersistenceHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA allows to define the mapping in XML using `orm.xml`. A real life exmaple can be found at [here](https://github.com/fogbeam/fogbeam_roller/blob/master/app/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml) and [here](https://github.com/fogbeam/fogbeam_roller/tree/master/app/src/main/resources/org/apache/roller/weblogger/pojos).

For me , though the POJO become more clean when the mapping is defined in `orm.xml` , it seems to require more effort when compared to annotation and also make the codes look like less readable and maintainable . I would be more pragmatic to just let them annotated with JPA annotations. If a module only need to use them as the plain POJO but not JPA entity , just not include the JPA implementation and the JPA annotation will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, I actually thought JPA annotation meant to be used strictly in JPA context.